# How does one say 'made up slang' and slang in other languages? 

Tags: support

Suppose I need to use or explain a hybrid (english mash-up) word to answer a question. How do I explain this to someone who is not a native speaker?

Comment: I don't follow what you're trying to ask.

Comment: its a translation question with difficult syntax....  perhaps best left to native english speakers so we can make it understood once we get it right

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slang
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pidgin

Comment: I understand what slang & pidgin is, I don't know what you're trying to ask. The question was moved to [webapps.se] because it asked for an online tool, which is offtopic per [su] [faq]

Comment: ah ok... so suppose i need to use or explain a hybrid (english mash-up) word to answer a question ... how do i explain this to someone who is not a native speaker?  the meta question still aapplies to superuser even if the spark does not.  the example I wanted to use in the other thing was just a trivial 'noooop' but with computers one (me anyway) often needs to make up a word to explain something right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not, see you could not even explain it here :-) What is a mash-up? and what does the question have to do with mixing music :-)

I write deep slang , make up new words , why not?  People made up the ones were using now, what makes them so special? I spell badly.
 I have attempted to discuss and explain high tech things that I have seen, or things I am doing . Usually that turns out very bad, 2 years later I go back to the posts I did when discovering something, and I can barely understand it myself.

All the people who are also english , understood the slang (or enough of it) and were trying to do the same things , at the same time, had little problem understanding it all, because they were involved in doing it too (at that time).
Often a person asking a Question, or doing the actual actions at the time, is not having as much trouble understanding it , as the people who are not involved with it, at that time.

We get to read all the terrible english from non-native speakers. Really bad computerised translations, Bad manuels, and help files, from people trying real hard to communicate in a "2nd language".  We get to be misunderstood and have people think what was said was "offencive" or incorrect.   It is great that somehow we can all communicate, but we cant be blamed for the universality of the web, or the 2nd language problems. (even if 1/2 of the 2nd language people use better english)

This is a world wide board, you have to speak so the world can understand:
I have heard of this opinion before, So where is the "American tech" board where everyone can understand really bad english and slang and I dont have to understand 27 different cultures?  It isn't DasUsers , the only russian looking text is in the code samples, and nothing reads right to left, so I must be in the right place :-)

The translator test:
I ran lots of text, and some posts I did through the "translater test" .  The translater test is done by taking what you write, computer translating it to a different language, then translating it back again to english, what is readable after that is almost universally understood, by machines and humans alike.  It is also void of any slang, creativity or humor, it reads at a 2nd grade level, and avoids using words longer than 5 letters , and must be spelled perfect.

As usual, where is this all going?
  Be as clear, and simple and . . . heck with that, just put up some pictures :-)
 http://www.comicmix.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Mash-Up-2.jpg

Comment: yeah i think you have the concept of 'mash up' based on your picture.  it is just mixing different things together whether film, music, or words.  my name 'conspiritech' is one i made up of 'conspiracy' 'spirit' and 'technology'.  http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=mash+up

Comment: I have no idea what you guys are talking about!

Comment: Dont worry, neither do I most of the time . http://xkcd.com/1010/

Answer (score 2):

> an·swer /ˈansər/
>
> **Noun:**
>   A thing said, written, or done to deal with or as a reaction to a question, statement, or situation.
>
> **Verb:**
>   Say or write something to deal with or as a reaction to someone or something.
>
> **Synonyms:**
>   noun.  reply - response - rejoinder - replication - return
>   verb.  respond - reply - rejoin - return

Just look it up in a dictionary and keep looking for words that could not be understand. Let's say he doesn't understand `reaction`, so we can look that one up to.

> re·ac·tion /rēˈakSHən/
>
> **Noun:**
>   An action performed or a feeling experienced in response to a situation or event: "Carrie's immediate reaction was one of relief".
>   A person's ability to respond physically and mentally to external stimuli.
>
> **Synonyms:**
>   response - counteraction

But then we'll need to know what `action` and `response` are.

> ac·tion /ˈakSHən/
>
> **Noun:**
>   The fact or process of doing something, typically to achieve an aim: "demanding tougher action against terrorism".
>   The way in which something such as a chemical has an effect or influence.
>
> **Synonyms:**
>   act - deed - operation - work - activity - doing - battle
>
> re·sponse /riˈspäns/
>
> **Noun:**
>   A verbal or written answer.
>   A written or verbal answer to a question in a test, questionnaire, survey, ...
>
> **Synonyms:**
>   reply - answer - rejoinder - reaction - replication

Ah, we're going in circles now. But by mashing them up somewhat we can get something like:

> A thing said, written or done to help solve the problem in the question; with the aim to achieve points and help people.